# Producing x and y-intersections automatically

Tags: pgfplots

How does one produce a picture of a function (say, a polynomial) and indicate the $x$- and $y$-intercepts automatically? I have some code that produces 1 of the $x$-intercepts and the $y$-intercept, but not the second $x$-intercept. It seems to work if the roots are distinct, but not when there is a repeated root.

As a related question, is there a better way to find such intersections than to define a zero function and the line segment at $x = 0$?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document} 


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=10cm,               
axis lines = middle,  
scaled ticks=false,
no marks,
xmax=5,xmin=-5,
ymin=-10,ymax=10,
xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
xtick={-5,...,5},
ytick={-10,...,10},
]

\addplot+[name path=A] {(1/2)*(x+3)*(x+3)*(x-2)};
\addplot[name path = xaxis,color=black]{0};
\addplot[name path = yaxis,color=black] coordinates {(0,-10) (0,10)};
node[draw,fill,circle,inner sep=2pt] at (2,0) {};

\path[name intersections={of=A and xaxis}]
      node[draw,fill,circle,inner sep=2pt%,pin={above left:Intersection}]
      ]        at (intersection-1) {};
      node[draw,fill,circle,inner sep=2pt%,pin={above left:Intersection}]
      ]        at (intersection-2) {};
      node[draw,fill,circle,inner sep=2pt%,pin={above left:Intersection}]
      ]        at (intersection-3) {};
\path[name intersections={of=A and yaxis}]
      node[draw,fill,circle,inner sep=2pt%,pin={above left:Intersection}]
      ]        at (intersection-1) {};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I would make it work like this;

Ad a line with the points (-3;0) (3;0) 
Make the intersection with that line with Tikz-euclid.

Answer (score 2):

The second intersection isn't marked because you've ended the path with `;` before drawing the node at `intersection-2`. So in the code in question, i.e.

```
\path[name intersections={of=A and xaxis}]
      node[draw,fill,circle,inner sep=2pt%,pin={above left:Intersection}]
      ]        at (intersection-1) {};
      node[draw,fill,circle,inner sep=2pt%,pin={above left:Intersection}]
      ]        at (intersection-2) {};
      node[draw,fill,circle,inner sep=2pt%,pin={above left:Intersection}]
      ]        at (intersection-3) {};
```

the last two nodes are simply ignored I think. There isn't even an `intersection-3`, so that would throw an error. If you remove the semicolon after the first node, i.e. end of line three in that snippet, it works fine.

Below I used a slightly less verbose way of drawing the dots at intersections with axes.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=10cm,               
axis lines = middle,  
scaled ticks=false,
no marks,
xmax=5,xmin=-5,
ymin=-10,ymax=10,
xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
xtick={-5,...,5},
ytick={-10,...,10},
clip mode=individual
]

\addplot+[name path=A,samples=100] {(1/2)*(x+3)*(x+3)*(x-2)};
\addplot[name path = xaxis,color=black]{0};
\addplot[name path = yaxis,color=black] coordinates {(0,-10) (0,10)};

\fill[name intersections={of=A and xaxis}]
     (intersection-1) circle[radius=3pt] 
     (intersection-2) circle[radius=3pt];

\fill[name intersections={of=A and yaxis}]
     (intersection-1) circle[radius=3pt];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```